# Configuration Manager: Configuring Active Directory System Discovery fails with ActiveDirectoryServerDownException

Tags: sccm-2007

I've just set up a new ConfigMgr 2007 SP1 environment for testing. I'm attempting to configure Client Push Installation, for which I want to use Active Directory System Discovery.

However, when I attempt to add "Local Domain" to the containers list, I get an `ActiveDirectoryServerDownException`. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that you should check is that DNS is working correctly. If you're using DHCP, have you configured DNS servers correctly in the DHCP server? If you're using static IP settings, have you configured DNS correctly there?

To check DNS, just run nslookup at a command prompt. Does it connect to the correct DNS server? Does it answer queries with the expected results?